# javaFX launch app error

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying to run this simple Javafx code:

```
public class Javafx extends Application
{
    Stage window;
    Scene scene1,scene2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        window = primaryStage;
        Label label1 = new Label("click here to go to scene 2");
        Button button1 = new Button("click here");
        button1.setOnAction(e-> window.setScene(scene2));
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(15);
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1,button1);
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1,700,900);

        Label label2 = new Label("get back to scene1");        
        Button button2 = new Button("press");
        button2.setOnAction(e-> window.setScene(scene1));
        StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
        label2.setRotate(70);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2,button2);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2,500,500);
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("Java FX");
        window.show();

    }
}
```

but for some reason after i'm closing the app and rerun it,iv'e got an error:
application luanch must not called more than once.
as far as i can tell,the launch app called only once,but the only way for me to rerun it again is to reset first the JVM .

can anyone tell me how can i overcome this?
i'm using Bluej if that's matter,

Comment: Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: This works fine for me, could it possibly be Bluej being smart and calling `launch()` for you? Try removing the main method and see what happens.